# Какие технологии использовать для управлениями вкладками Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, python, веб-программирование, selenium

ситуация следующая. У меня открыто окно браузера (Google Chrome). В этом окне находятся две вкладки. Каждая вкладка имеет  одинаковый URL, но каждая вкладка уникальна тем что она по  своему настроена  и авторизированна (через расширение браузера, позволяющее запускать вкладки в песке (SessionBox)). Моя цель - это написать программу, в которой будет присутствовать управление различными объектами на странице сайта какой либо вкладки, декстоп интерфейс то я написал, но проблема заключается что я не знаю как программно идентифицировать нужную мне вкладку. Пробовал сделать как-то через Selenium, но у него свойство постоянно делать запуск нового окна браузера, нежели как-то взаимодействовать с уже активным браузером.

Comment: Взгляните на [Chrome Extensions API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/) - возмножно это то что вам нужно

Comment: через selenium.

Comment: Селениум горазд только открывать новые окна, которые изолированы от основного браузера